# ble trouble with IONIC 2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic2

I am creating an app with ionic 2 and am trying to work with the [`ble-plugin`](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central). I ran the installation:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central
```

then wrote the following in my page's TS:

import {Page, Alert, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'
})

export class HelloIonicPage {

        constructor(public nav: NavController) { }
        bleScan() {
            ble.scan([], 5, function(device) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(device));
            }, failure);
        }
}
```

However, `ble` isn't recognised so my code is throwing errors. Do I need to inject a dependancy or something, why isn't this working?

Comment: At least you should add your errors log here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add import as following:

```
import {BLE} from 'ionic-native';
```

and use it like this:

```
 BLE.scan([], 5).subscribe(device => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(device));
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> First add top your page in TS

```
import {BLE} from 'ionic-native'
```

> Just use in your TS page

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        BLE.enable();

        BLE.startScan([]).subscribe(device => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(device));              
        },
            err => {
                //this.message = "Error";
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before use ble, you need import it first.

Comment: This should have been an enquiry comment, not an answer

Comment: What do I import and from where? There is nothing I can see in the docs or in the examples. The source is imported as a plugin, not a standard node_module

Answer (score 0):

Try this? I'm also stumbling on a ionic 2 project that will involve BLE API use, but I haven't started doing it yet.
http://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/